# <html ng-app="app"> convert to single-spa will make directives in the index.html disappear

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have an angular.js app where the **index.html** looks something like with `ng-app` in the `<html>` tag

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <custom-navbar-directive></custom-navbar-directive> //angular js directive
      <custom-loader></custom-loader>

      <!-- To render components -->
      <div ui-view ng-cloak></div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I was following the steps in the [single-spa angular.js guide](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angularjs). I removed the `ng-app` from `<html>` tag and added the following in my **app.js**

```
System.register([], function (_export) {
  return {
    execute: function () {
      _export(
        window.singleSpaAngularjs.default({
          angular: angular,
          mainAngularModule: "app",
          uiRouter: true,
          preserveGlobal: false,
        })
      );
    },
  };
});
```

Also I did the import map and `singleSpa.registerApplication`  steps in the **index.html**
My issue is now the content is rendering but the `<custom-navbar-directive>` and `<custom-loader>`  are missing. I added them inside the **index.html** since they are commonly used in each html template.
When I inspect and checked the rendered html I noticed that they are outside the loaded single spa angularjs app

```html
<custom-navbar-directive></custom-navbar-directive>
<custom-loader></custom-loader>

<div id="single-spa-application:legacyAngularApp">
  <div id="__single_spa_angular_1" class="ng-scope">
       <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess since they are directives if those are inside the `<div id="__single_spa_angular_1" class="ng-scope">` then it should render.
Any idea how to solve this?